How can I align the numbers to the top of the cells?
I want to align the numbers to the top left corners of each cell. I was able to find the set_text_props, but it isn't doing the alignment as I expect.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.axis('off')

table = ax.table(
    cellText=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
              [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],
    loc='center',
    cellLoc='left',
)

table.set_fontsize(10)
table.scale(1, 4)

for (row, col), cell in table.get_celld().items():
    cell.set_text_props(va='bottom')


Delving into the code that sets the text positioning at render time for the table Cell class here, I don't think what you want to do is currently possible. I think you'd have to write your own custom Cell class that does the positioning as you want it.

It might be worth opening an issue (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues) stating the problem and requesting the feature you need.

(This is a hack, not a solution)
Add a newline to your text and adjust the cell.PAD.
colab

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.axis('off')

cellText=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
          [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
for i in range(len(cellText)):
    for j in range(len(cellText[i])):
        cellText[i][j] = f"{cellText[i][j]}\n"

table = ax.table(
    cellText=cellText,
    loc='center',
    cellLoc='left',
)

table.set_fontsize(10)
table.scale(1, 4)

for (row, col), cell in table.get_celld().items():
    cell.set_text_props(va='bottom')
    cell.PAD=0.05

